# Action requires users leave and interact with another site, how to ensure they come back?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, design-patterns

I have a scenario in which a user must copy code from a Site A, paste it into the source code of Site B, then return to Site A to confirm the action was successful.

What's the best way to make ensure the user reliably returns to Site A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard verification scenario, the most common example of which is domain verification. i.e. when setting up Google Analytics a user must paste a meta tag in the homepage on the site to prove they have access.

The key is to **require a verification or confirmation step on Site A**, and to make sure it's obvious from the interaction design that the user must return. e.g.

1. Copy this code
2. Paste into Site B in location X
3. Return and verify/confirm to complete

This way you set the expectation that a return trip is required. A user is much less likely to paste the code into Site B and then think "Now what?"

In the case of Google Analytics set up, returning to Site A (GA) is a requirement. If you don't go back and click the "Verify Domain" button, you can't progress. You might consider rethinking your the workflow build in such a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a relationship / association with the other site you can frame them allowing your users to never "leave" your site (although in practice they do). *

If you don't have an association with them then there isn't anything else you can do but write compelling copy explaining the benefits to the user for leaving and coming back. You can add incentives (rewards) to the user for doing so in addition - but once they leave your site - they've left.

- You can't frame an external site if they don't give you permission.